# WCF client with signing and encryption + HTTPS with four certificates

Tags: wcf, soap, certificate, interop, ws-security

I have to make an WCF client for one external SOAP web-service written probably in Java. That web-service uses **WS-Security** for signing and encryption (so, I suppose I have to use WCF message level security). Transport mechanism between client and web-service is **HTTPS with 2-way handshaking**.

The problem is that I have to use four different certificates - let us call them **CertA**, **CertB**, **CertC** and **CertD**.

- **CertA** and **CertC** must be used for signing the SOAP message.
- **CertB** and **CertD** must be used for SOAP message encryption and HTTPS handshaking.

Basically, the client is supposed to sign a message using it's private key and encrypt the message using server's public key. The server do the opposite.

Precisely, here's what WCF client have to do in order to send a message to the server and receive the response back:

1. Client sign SOAP request with certificate **CertA** (using CertA's
   private key)
2. Client encrypt SOAP request with certificate **CertD**
   (using CertD's public key)
3. Client send signed and encrypted SOAP message over HTTPS to the server (certificate **CertB** is required by the server during HTTPS 2-way handshaking for authentication purpose)

On the server side:

4. Server receives the message, authenticate and authorize client
5. Server decrypt message with **CertD**'s private key
6. Server verify message signature with **CertA**'s public key. Server then process decrypted and verified message.
7. Server create response message and sign it with certificate **CertC** (using CertC's private key)
8. Server encrypts the response message with certificate **CertB** (using CertB's public key)
9. Server send response back to the client over HTTPS transport.

When client receive the server response:

10. Client decrypt response with its **CertB**'s private key
11. Client verify message signature with **CertC**'s public key
12. Client process the response.

The question is *how to configure such WCF client?* Which binding to use to enable SOAP signing & encryption on message layer + HTTPS 2-way handshake on the transport layer and how to "tell" WCF what's the purpose of each of the 4 certificates?

(Yes, I already saw this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729856(v=vs.110).aspx but I'm afraid that article doesn't provide solution for my case because they use some weird duplex binding which require a client to open an listening port and that's not an option for me since I have to use regular HTTPS connection).

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?